How to include or not include Rails module based on condition?
In my Ruby on Rails app I have this model:
class Car < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :name, :brand, :origin_country

  module ShippingCostCalculatorForJapan

    def calculate
      # Details left out for brevity
    end

    # A bunch of other expensive methods

 end

 module ShippingCostCalculatorForGermany

   def calculate
     # Details left out for brevity
   end

   # A bunch of other expensive methods

 end

end

How can I make it that only the relevant module gets loaded?
For example if I have a car object with origin_country "Japan", only the module ShippingCostCalculatorForJapan should be applied.
How can this be done or what might be a better (= best practice) design pattern to achieve this?
As it stands now, I have a bunch of different CostCalculator modules all containing the exact same methods but with different values in them. The values are hardcoded to the respective country and can't be changed.
I could also easily re-organize those modules into classes. What would be the best approach here?

The ShippingCostCalculator... modules are plain Ruby objects? If so, I would turn them into classes (maybe with a common base class) and move them out of the Car model. Then implement a Car#shipping_cost_calculator method that returns an instance of the correct class based on origin_country.

Are you sure you cannot share anything between the different ShippingcostCalulators ? Because that would make sens to turn it into a Service object and call it by passing the car record. ShippingCostCalculator.new.calculate(car_record: self) Then your service object can use anything from the record such as shipping destination... You can also share methods.

You are probably looking for Single Table Inheritance or STI. Just add a "type" column in the table.
class Car < ApplicationRecord
end

class JapaneseCar < Car
end

class GermanCar < Car
end

You will still only have 1 table (cars), and you can act on the whole table as usual through the Car model.
Car.where(year_of_manufacture: 2024) # example

But when the record gets loaded from the database, it becomes either a JapaneseCar or a GermanCar. Put any shared code in the Car class and country-specific code in the country-specific class.

Thanks. That does indeed make a lot of sense. The only thing that bothers me is that I am already using STI on the Car class (I left out a lot of code above for brevity) and that it already features a relatively high number of _type columns. So I wonder if there's an alternative solution to the problem which I may not be aware of.

I'm not convinced that this actually solves anything. Does a Japanese car really need different behavior than a German car? Why is Car even concerned with calculating shipping in the first place?

It really depends on what you mean by "based on condition". In Ruby class defintion is just a block of code and you can use any logic you want to decide what to include:
class Foo
  # I'm not saying this is a good idea. Just that it's possible.
  include TestHelpers if Rails.env.test?
end

However what Module#includes does is place a module on the ancestors chain of the class so using it to include different modules in different instances of the same class is not possible and just doesn't make sense.
If you really want to do that you can use Object#extend:
class Car < ApplicationRecord
 # You don't need/want to use attr_accessor
 module ShippingCostCalculatorForJapan
   def calculate
     puts "Calculating costs for Japan"
   end
 end

 module ShippingCostCalculatorForGermany
   def calculate
     puts "Calculating costs for Germany"
   end
 end
end

m = Car.new(brand: 'Mazda')
m.extend(Car::ShippingCostCalculatorForJapan)
m.calculate # "Calculating costs for Japan"

g = Car.new(brand: 'Mercedes-Benz')
g.extend(Car::ShippingCostCalculatorForGermany)
g.calculate # "Calculating costs for Germany"

While this is a handy trick for limiting the effects of monkeypatching it's not exactly a very good way to design software. Determening where a method comes from shouldn't require detective work.
And that's kind of the core of the problem here - you need to find the right abstraction for the domain and separate between logic and data instead of just trying to salvage a broken design.
I would recommend that you start by completely separating Car and the responsibility of calculating shipping.
In Rails models already have an insane amount of responsiblities:

Typecasting
Dirty tracking
Persistence
Querying
Callbacks
Validations
Serialization
...

Don't add to that list.
